# Do I still need to ping Google after changing a sitemap nowadays?

Tags: seo, sitemap, robots.txt

Months ago I've implemented SEO in a website and it was recommended that every time that the sitemaps changed I should ping this URL http://www.google.com/ping?sitemap=http://mywebsite.com/sitemap.xml.

Now i'm implementing again but I can't find in Google documentation anything about ping after sitemap change. All the articles that mention this technique are old.

Is it deprecated or do I still need to ping?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Google's official Search Central dev docs](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/sitemaps/build-sitemap) (under the Submit Your Sitemap to Google section), they still require you to ping them when you change your sitemap to make sure it gets crawled. Otherwise, they crawl it once "the first time [they] notice it."

Answer (score 2):

Google sitemap ping has been deprecated. You can find out the info from [Google source](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2023/06/sitemaps-lastmod-ping)